# What is the word denoting the crime of taking advantage of person under one's authority, sexual or otherwise?

Tags: legalese

It's a common legal term that has just slipped my mind, and I can't seem to find a reference for it.

Thank you.

Comment: You might get a better answer if you ask on the law SE.

Comment: [**Exploitation**](https://www.coxwelllaw.com/exploitation-of-minors.html) is a word that can describe this, but I don't know if it's the one you want.

Comment: You might be thinking of [***malfeasance***.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abuse_of_power#:~:text=Abuse%20of%20power%20or%20abuse,the%20performance%20of%20official%20duties.) Or just ***abuse** [of power]*.

Comment: Your question is too broad. There are many ways to take advantage of someone under your authority. Most of them are not crimes.